Python Script that operates when google sheets is changed

I am trying to use this script to send data to this python function

but

"Error: { [Exception: Bad request: http://127.0.0.1:5000/on-edit]"

always happens. Is there a way to fix this?
I am trying to send data from a google sheet to a python app, but failling

Apps script runs on  Google's server. It can't access your local endpoint,unless you tunnel it through something lile ngrok.

Please post the code as a text, not a screenshot.

Usually, you can't simply copy-paste code with IP addresses and port numbers. Read up on 127.0.0.1, it is a special case. Then see if you can replace it with the IP address and port of the server hosting the Python script.

To make an app capable of listening to HTTP requests from an online platform like Google Apps Script, you should get a public IP address from your ISP and set your app to listen to that IP address or use an online platform. I don't know if Google Colab can listen to HTTP requests but it might be worth that you take some time to learn, first about HTTP requests and then about online platforms that supports scripts like the one that you are looking to make work.
